# Risk involved in NTFS auto mount

Tags: dual-boot, mount, ntfs

I have Windows 10 and 18.04 dual boot. There are 2 partitions from Windows 10 in NTFS which I use in Ubuntu to access files. It simply clicking the icon in `Other Locations`. I want your valued opinion about whether or not I should auto mount these partitions. Mainly because media is stored in these and audio and video player shows error due to missing file location. I know this is a simple thing, but I often forget to click on the partition icon before accessing media through VLC or Rythmbox and end up with the error message. Which at times is very frustrating.

I would have already used some guide and have set auto mount. But I am not sure whether there is any risk involved in this action. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, can you please reword your question (opinions are off topic), eg: What are the technical risks and disadvantages to automounting an NTFS partition used to dual boot between Ubuntu and Windows 10 ? Feel free to keep the background info, but ensure you have a clear objective question set.

Comment: Generally best not to mount Windows system partition or mount read/only. A read/write mount gives total admin control that Windows typically hides. You can mount other NTFS data partitions, but must have Windows fast start up off. And use better parameters to have it work better. Disks uses terrible parameters. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation I have seen various mount options. But include these: `windows_names,big_writes` in addition.

Comment: I am planning to do Ubuntu only. But will keep the set-up intact. Does your suggestion change in such a case ? Thanks.

Comment: I think @oldfred was saying that,  if you ever let Windows mount the partition, Windows could (via fastboot), render the partition UNmountable. If you tell Ubuntu "mount this partition at startup", and it's unmountable, startup will wait forever, and you'll be stuck.

Comment: If you keep or have a NTFS partition and no Windows, you will have trouble. Linux tools cannot fix NTFS issues. Best to only use Linux formats like ext4. If you must have NTFS, create a Windows repair/recovery flash drive so you can run chkdsk & defrag.